# What technology/jutsu do the Akatsuki members use to communicate with each other?

Tags: naruto

In the anime, it is shown that the Akatsuki members communicate with each other from the place they were currently present. What is that technology or jutsu?

Comment: I guess it will be form of telepathy or sort of and pein also have ability to manipulate certain objects remotely like antennas

Comment: Or maybe they just use "stick-to-the-plan" technique. =)

Comment: They also use Zetsu to communicate as well.

Answer (score 8):

This would be the [Magic Lantern Body Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Lantern_Body_Technique)

[image]

> ...The Akatsuki members sit down and send out "thought waves" (思念波, shinenha), converted into chakra. These thought waves are then picked up by Pain, acting as a kind of control tower. This technique amplifies the thought waves and broadcasts them to a specific location through illusionary bodies. The illusionary bodies differ from being mere reflections. While Pain is relaying the members' thoughts, they can have conversation and use varying techniques...

From Nagato's [wiki page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nagato) under *Ninjutsu*

> While acting through the Deva Path, Nagato displayed a wide range of techniques. Nagato was responsible for Akatsuki's meetings by using *a technique that allowed him to pick up their thought waves and broadcast them* in the form of an astral projection to a specific location.

Answer (score 1):

Accorrding to [this](http://www.narutohurricane.com/character-bios/akatsuki-leader.shtml), Pain "has a telepathy-like ability that allows Akatsuki members to communicate with each other through astral projection wherever they are located."